# I just want to know whether i can compare parts of string in pl/sql.

Tags: plsql

for example if i have a string "P_TRANSACTION" i should check another string which matched "%TRANSACTION"

P_TRANSACTION = "%TRANSACTION"

i have used substr(string, index ) to extract a part of string

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you are looking for.  There is `like` for comparing parts of strings e.g. `p_transaction like '%abc%'` would find strings that contain 'abc'.

Comment: Hi Tony,  i have a string which contains value as "P_Transaction" and i need to check if any other column in the db have value like "%Transaction" and if have string like "P_ABC" i need to search for a column value like "%ABC"

Comment: Something like `other_column like '%' || substr(the_string, 3)` ?

Comment: not understand our question correctly but try this sql

Comment: Please shoe a clear working example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

not understand your question correctly butTry this sql

```
select * from user_tab_cols where column_name like  '%'||ltrim('P_TRANSACTION','P_')
```

or

just user instr function like bellow

```
select instr('P_TRANSACTION','TRANSACTION') from dual;
```

it will return you non zero value in this case 3 if you got 0 then it mean you search string is not in original(base) string. may be you need to apply logic something bellow

```
declare
  v_result number;
begin
  select instr('P_TRANSACTION', 'TRANSACTION') into v_result from dual;
  if v_result <> 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('True');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('false');
  end if;
end;
```